# How to use UUID as a default value for HSQLDB column

Tags: hsqldb

I'm using HSQLDB for in memory database tests and I've run into problems when using UUID's as primary keys. I want my primary key to be generated by the database. The generated UUID doesn't have to be a real uuid, it just has to go to a varchar column.

I've tried UUID function that should exists according to this documentation: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html

```
alter table owner alter column id set default UUID();
```

But it just says that UUID is unexpected token.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a trigger for UUID column values.

```
CREATE TABLE OWNER ( ID BINARY(16) DEFAULT X'' PRIMARY KEY , VAL VARCHAR(10))
CREATE TRIGGER TRIG BEFORE INSERT ON OWNER REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NEW FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.ID = UUID();
```

Note the column needs a default, but this default is overwritten by the UUID()

Comment: Thanks, this works. Though "OWNER REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NEW" doesn't work if you don't remove the ROW-word